# Interpretation of parametrization

Tags: real-analysis, parametric

Let $f(t)=(x(t),y(t))'$ for $t\in[0,1]$, represents a parametric function.

Let us consider a parametric equation (straightline) joining two points $a$ and $b$ in 2-dimension:
$$f(t)=a(1-t)+bt.$$

Let us consider map $\gamma:t\mapsto t^2$, and consider the re-parametrization 
$$f(\gamma)=a(1-t^2)+bt^2.$$

My question is: what is the interpretation of this re-parametrization?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking about an interpretation other than "it's the same curve"? Do you have any interpretation of the original parameterization other than "it's that curve"?

Comment: I modified the question slightly. Here though the two curves are same, but the way they are varying with $t$, are  different. How to interpret this?

Comment: What is the way the first parameterization "varies with $t$"? Do you have an interpretation of that? I'm trying to imagine what you would consider an interpretation vs. what is just a formal manipulation.

Comment: Ok, consider the simple straight line parametric functions $f(t)=at+(1-t)b$, and $f(t^2)$, where $a$ and $b$ are contants. Observe that both indicate the same line, but have different speed.

Comment: I think I have not described the question well. I re-organised the question and posted it. Hope this will works.

Comment: Other than being a different parameterisation, it is hard to understand what you mean by interpretation.